# IDEA can not stop at the breakpoint at debug mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IDEA 2018.0.5 (Ultimate edition), and I suddenly find that IDEA can not stop at the breakpoints.

I am sure the codes conain the breakpoint have ran, since I have the log, but it does not stop.

How to resolve that problum.

Comment: Have you maybe changed you code after and not redeployed it/not restarted the program? Is your breakpoint at a "reachable" location? The breakpoint icon should have a little "tick" inside it, if it is reachable.

Comment: Not an IDEA at hand, but it could be the case when one compiles with no line numbers for debug (a stack trace does not show line numbers). Also eclipse for instance has a toggle button icon to suppress halting at break points. Maybe IDEA introduced similar functionality see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-disabling-and-removing-breakpoints.html